# Can SNS Topic be a source to EventBridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-event-bridge

quick question. I am planning to minimize use of resources by passing SNS topic as a source to EventBridge instead of passing it thru Lambda, then from EventBridge to Firehose. I tried but it is not working. Is it possible, or Lambda is the only way to make it as a source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its **not possible**. The only valid subscriptions to a SNS topic [are](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html):

```
    For the http protocol, the (public) endpoint is a URL beginning with http://.

    For the https protocol, the (public) endpoint is a URL beginning with https://.

    For the email protocol, the endpoint is an email address.

    For the email-json protocol, the endpoint is an email address.

    For the sms protocol, the endpoint is a phone number of an SMS-enabled device.

    For the sqs protocol, the endpoint is the ARN of an Amazon SQS queue.

    For the application protocol, the endpoint is the EndpointArn of a mobile app and device.

    For the lambda protocol, the endpoint is the ARN of an AWS Lambda function.

    For the firehose protocol, the endpoint is the ARN of an Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream.
```

But SNS can push **directly to Firehose**, so maybe just do this.

Comment: Oh okay got it. yup I tested SNS to Firehose and seems to work. it's just that I want to use EventBridge so I can fire it out to many targets. I noticed that SNS could be used as event source but particularly as AWS event, not the SNS message sent to a specific topic right?

Comment: @CharmeeLee That's correct. You can use SNS as AWS events, but not for sending messages to EB. For that you need sns topic subscription, which does not support EB.

Answer (score 0):

Has something changed since the last answer? Now it is possible to set `aws.sns` as source for an EventBridge rule (as shown in the below picture), but it does not seem to trigger the rule anyway... The question is, why do the AWS team let the users select `aws.sns` as source if it cannot work?

[image]

Comment: It might be referring to the CloudTrail events that are associated with SNS. Not, the messages that placed in the SNS topic; but not sure.